# Spark dataset shows schema but throws UnsupportedOperation exception for show() method

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

Have created a Spark dataset using a bean encoder of custom java class

```
Encoder<CustomJavaType> customJavaEncoder = Encoders.bean(CustomJavaType.class);
Dataset<CustomJavaType> customJavaTypeDataset = sparkRunner.getSparkConfig().getSparkSession()
.createDataset(listofCustomJavaTypeObjects, customJavaEncoder);
```

customJavaTypeDataset.printschema() works just fine. It shows the schema correctly.

However, customJavaTypeDataset.show() throws the following exception

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot grow BufferHolder by size 0 because the size after growing exceeds size limitation 2147483647
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.BufferHolder.grow(BufferHolder.java:65)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.UnsafeRowWriter.write(UnsafeRowWriter.java:214)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply2_2$(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalTableScanExec$$anonfun$unsafeRows$1.apply(LocalTableScanExec.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalTableScanExec$$anonfun$unsafeRows$1.apply(LocalTableScanExec.scala:41)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalTableScanExec.unsafeRows$lzycompute(LocalTableScanExec.scala:41)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalTableScanExec.unsafeRows(LocalTableScanExec.scala:36)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalTableScanExec.executeTake(LocalTableScanExec.scala:72)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:2861)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2150)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$55.apply(Dataset.scala:2842)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:2841)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2150)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2363)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:241)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:637)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:596)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:605)
```

All the nested classes of CustomJavaType implements serializable.
Number of objects in the list is 5.
printSchema is as expected.

Comment: Can you share your full code with custom java class?

Comment: @Thirumal Did you get this resolved? We have a similar issue where the printSchema all looks good but fails with a similar error when we try to write the dataset to a Parquet file.

Comment: No. Somehow bean encoder is not working. I ended up creating an elaborate schema using StructType to build dataset.

Comment: I believe I have tracked down the spot that triggers this error, but I don't have any idea how to fix it. I guess you can't add images to a comment, so I'm going to add what I'm seeing as an answer instead ...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a solution to the problem (see my comment above), but it may help someone get a bit closer ...

I believe I have tracked down the point in code that triggers this error. It is in spark-catalyst_2.11-2.2.0:/.../org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/UnsafeRow.java:getUTF8String line 418. On that line a "long" is cast to an "int", but the value is too large for an int, and the wrapped value results in a negative number which is then used in an attempt to grow a byte buffer (somewhere along the line, a java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException is thrown and swallowed/ignored).

Ultimately we arrive at spark-catalyst_2.11-2.2.0:/.../org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/codegen/BufferHolder.java:grow line 64 where an if() statement mistakes the negative value for a too-big value, thus throwing the UnsupportedOperationException.

I'm not sure what to do with this info. Maybe somebody knows. Is this the sort of thing that should be reported as a bug?

Here are a couple of visuals from my debugger to show the detail:
[image: getUTF8String__spark-catalyst_2.11-2.2.0__org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.png]

[image: grow__spark-catalyst_2.11-2.2.0__org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.BufferHolder.png]